# how to burn subtitles and transcode live stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I try to transcode live stream and scale the video i have managed to do this with this command :

> ffmpeg -i "udp://@239.253.251.14:5505?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000"    -vf scale=720:576    -b:v 2600k -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M   -b:a 128k  -f mpegts "udp://@239.253.251.15:5505?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000&pkt_size=1316&&buffer_size=10000000"

but now i have to  burn subtitles from the same source and output it with the scaled video. I don't know how to do this .Please any help would be appreciated.
Here is the source stream:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.253.251.14:5505':
  Duration: N/A, start: 29246.522044, bitrate: N/A
  Program 761
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?
      service_provider: ?
    Stream #0:0[0x105]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xe1b](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1203](srp): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:3[0x1204](slv): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x1205](mkd): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:5[0x1206](hrv): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0x1207](alb): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
```

i need to burn -> Stream #0:20x1203: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)

i have also tried :

> ffmpeg -i "udp://@239.253.251.14:5505?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000&pkt_size=1316&&buffer_size=10000000"      -b:v 2600k -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M   -b:a 128k  -vf scale=720:576 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:2]overlay[v]" -map "[v]"  -f mpegts "udp://@239.253.251.15:5505?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000&pkt_size=1316&&buffer_size=10000000"

but the error was:
Filtergraph 'scale=720:576' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

Comment: move scale into complex filter: -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=720:576[0v];[0v][0:s:2]overlay[v]" or something like this